# Completed solutions. Need your advice

Tags: feature-request, magento

I have faced with a lot of different questions, where the problem is not very clear. To understand this problem I need to ask author do some steps. For example author has a problem with layout. And you start explaining what to do. In most situations the explanation is similar.

I thought that maybe I can create some blog post or create wiki post and give that link to author.

Does it make sense? If yes - please advice where to store such solutions? Do stackexchange has some resources for that purpose?

Answer (score 4):

I understand. Magento is complex, and especially for a new user it is not possible to get them to refine their question without dialogue. This can be done in comments or by edits to your answer as more context becomes available.

Here's some guidance: remember that Stack is here for all of the people who will come after in search of help, not just for the OP. This means that the full context for the question and answer should be *here* on the site. Linking to any offsite resource on its own is not enough, because if the link breaks the "answer" does too. Also, frequently linking to your own blog will have an appearance of self-promotion which is not welcome here. You can link to your blog if you like for providing long-form, deep instruction, just make sure that there is sufficient content here at Stack for future users in case the link breaks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Can I use page http://magento.stackexchange.com/tags/layout/info for advices debugging layout? And in other similar sittuations?